# OpenERP Insert multiple records at once

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
if values['section_id']:
        custom_dept=[{'name':name,'complete_name':complete_name,'company_id':company_id,'parent_id':parent_id,'manager_id':manager_id},
                    {'name':name,'complete_name':complete_name,'company_id':company_id,'parent_id':parent_id,'manager_id':manager_id},
                    {'name':name,'complete_name':complete_name,'company_id':company_id,'parent_id':parent_id,'manager_id':manager_id}]
    department_obj.create(cr, uid, custom_dept, context=context)
```

i need solution like above.can anyone help me to implement this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the create method as that inserts a single record. You could do this with a SQL query but I wouldn't recommend it. Remember that OpenERP wraps everything in a PostgreSQL transaction so your records will all get inserted if you run the create command in a loop.

Comment: Thanks dear friend Adrian.I also used '.create()' function at four times and its solved now. :-)